# Can a handgun shot take down a commercial airliner?

Tags: safety

Most airplanes, when taking off or landing, are in range of small arms fire, i.e. your every day handgun.

Is it possible to take down a commercial airliner by shooting at it with a handgun? Would one shot be enough, or would several be needed?

Comment: This may be a bit broad. The weakest link is probably the pilots, and [it doesn't even require a gun](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2817/1696).

Comment: My question isn't, "what's the easiest way to take down an airliner". It's quite specific.

Comment: I would imagine the answer must be 'yes'.  [Aircraft have been shot down with rifles](http://www.airspacemag.com/daily-planet/first-aerial-combat-victory-180952933/?no-ist) after all.

Comment: Interesting read, however not a modern commercial airline.

Comment: This might be theoretically possible if you got a really, _really_ lucky shot, but it's incredibly unlikely. Nearly everything critical to flight safety (including the flight crew!) is redundant in a modern airliner with many of the systems being triply redundant. For a single shot to take one down would be incredibly lucky (or unlucky, depending on your point of view.) Even emptying a mag into one seems extremely unlikely to actually take it down. Consider that modern airliners have [had engines violently explode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32) without even any injuries.

Comment: @SteveV.: Interesting link, but poorly researched. When the Italians attacked the Turks in Lybia in 1913, the Turkish side hired French pilots with their planes to fight the Italians. It was **then** when the first shots between planes were fired, and aerial victories scored.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, while the answers may vary, it is quite possible to provide an academic answer.

Comment: Related: [Accident: PIA A313 at Peshawar on Jun 24th 2014, aircraft under gun fire on final approach](http://avherald.com/h?article=476566da). It was a bigger gun and multiple shots, but while it managed to kill one and injure another two persons on board, it didn't do much damage to the aircraft itself.

Comment: "your everyday handgun" - Welcome to America, y'all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> shooting at it with a handgun

That's really going to depend on the handgun.

James Bond carries a Walther PPK - this is a .32 calibre popgun with rather limited use outside of a small office. Direct hits on *people* are usually survivable unless you take a round in the heart or brain. Chances of even hitting an airliner during takeoff or approach are zero - it simply doesn't have the range, and that tiny subsonic projectile will get deflected by the aircraft's wake.

Skipping the middle range and going straight for the hand-cannons, we might get somewhere with a Desert Eagle or a Smith & Wesson 500. Remember the posters for the first Terminator movie? The one where The Ah-nuld is wearing sunglasses and holding up some light artillery? These are bigger. At close range, both guns can crack an aluminum engine block<sup>1</sup> and are one-shot kills on most things smaller than a rhino. Hitting an approaching widebody isn't all that difficult - it's coming toward you, the angle isn't changing, and it's a rather big target.

But aircraft are large, complex systems with a lot of redundancy, so in order to actually take it down we have to hit something critical. Hitting a 767 right in the nose will destroy the weather radar and (maybe, if it has enough energy left) poke a 1/2 inch hole in the forward bulkhead. No one will notice. The flight-deck windows are rather strong, apparently a police sniper tried to take out a hijacker on the flight deck way back in the 1970s and the rifle round (far more powerful) just pock-marked the window. Several hostages were promptly shot as a result.

The best shot (ha!) is the engines. They don't like ingesting bits of metal but just hitting the fan won't do much. You would have to get very lucky to get the round into the engine itself, where it will promptly do a lot of very expensive damage.

But even if one engine literally goes boom it *still* won't crash the plane. Pilots practice for an engine failure on takeoff all the time, and an engine failure on landing is almost a non-event.

Hydraulic lines for control surfaces are certainly sensitive, but they are well buried in the structure and there are several independent systems. You won't get them all.

So, in conclusion, handguns are sufficiently ineffective at bringing down large aircraft that we really don't need to be concerned about them. There's a reason air forces around the world prefer missiles or 20mm cannon<sup>2</sup> for this sort of thing. Geese, however, are quite effective if released in sufficient numbers along the takeoff path. Rather noisy though - you won't hide 500 of them anywhere near an airport without someone noticing.

---

1. Internet legends of a .50 cal being able to kill a truck refer to the MUCH larger .50 BMG round, available in explosive and armour-piercing and rightfully categorized as a first-class military weapon.
2. The projectile's the size of your thumb, and the gun fires 6,000 rounds per minute. It'll do your plane like a chainsaw.

Comment: The Walther PPK projectile gets deflected by the aircraft's wake? Come on! Check your facts!

Comment: It's *tiny* - 5 grams. And it's subsonic leaving the barrel. I don't mean it's going to bounce off like the Enterprise's deflector shield but it will drift off target a lot more than heavier rounds. A decent crosswind can move a rifle round meters off target and they have a lot more energy. You need mass and energy here, and a .32ACP lacks both.

Comment: The wake is behind the aircraft. If the wake had any effect, the shooters aim would be far off target. Besides, it would only affect a small portion of the projectile's path. Crosswind works for the full length, that is why it makes such a difference.

Comment: Alright, lets forget the widebody-class wake for a minute. If you are shooting at me from ~200 meters away with a .32ACP I am going to stay right where I am: the aiming point is the least likely place you will hit. I will laugh and make disparaging comments about your marksmanship. Take out one of the other two and I will be leaving at Usain Bolt speeds.

Comment: I imagine if you shot a blade and it spit the blade into the compressor that the results would be pretty devastating.  If sparrows can take out engines...  You'd still, of course, be left with an operable engine and be fully capable of landing the airplane.

Comment: @RhinoDriver maybe. But the aircraft can get lucky too. During flight testing of the F/A-18 prototype the pilot noticed a weird vibration in one of the engines and decided to land and investigate. Turned out one of the front fan blades was missing. There was some damage inside the engine suggesting it had gone all the way through, but the engine still more or less functioned (it was replaced).

Comment: FWIW, in my imagination a shot to take down a commercial airliner would come from a position in front of the plane, in other words the plane would be making it's takeoff run towards me. I think that would eliminate wake turbulence.

Comment: It should be noted that there is at least one [.50 BMG handgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Action_Thunder).

Answer (score 9):

It depends where the shot is fired and what counts as "taking down".

If you fire a handgun inside the cabin during a regular flight, the pilot will likely divert to the next airport and land. The aircraft is "down", but probably not in the way you were thinking of.

If you fire at the plane from the outside, in most cases the result will only be detected at the next bigger inspection. If you are "lucky" and hit something important, a system might fail and the airplane is marked for repair after landing. But it will not go down in flames.

For the way the question was probably intended to be asked, my answer is No.

Comment: There's one way it will bring the plane down: shoot one, or especially both, of the pilots.

Comment: @raptortech97: To kill both pilots with a single handgun shot from the outside during takeoff or landing (as the question implies) is in the range of will-I-be-struck-by-a-comet likely.

Comment: You're totally right. For a while there I completely forgot how inaccurate handguns are (and how accurate one would have to be).

Comment: As I remember, at the first 747 carrier I worked for, a few bullet holes were found in the vertical stabilizer of one of the aircraft, a freighter, when it was undergoing routine maintenance. The aircraft had been through Mogadishu some weeks earlier, and that was felt to be the best candidate as to when it had happened.

Comment: How about a shot at the fuel tank area? Would that just cause a leak?

Comment: @Sandy: Yes. Nothing more. The tanks are filled with kerosene, which is hard to ignite, and what is not filled with fuel is taken up by an oxygen-reduced inert gas which prevents combustion. The tank would just pee a thin stream of fuel. In an extreme scenario, the aircraft has just braked hard, then taken off, and the fuel pees on the red-glowing wheel brakes. Now the plane would trail a small flame, but this would still not be enough to ignite the fuel in the tanks. Real life ≠ Hollywood.

Comment: @raptortech97 not just (or not so much) accurate as powerful. Handguns lack the range and penetrating power to reach an aircraft during takeoff or landing (from a position outside the airport runway system), penetrate the cockpit walls or windows, go through even one of the flight crew (let alone both), and leave a hole in them big enough to be fatal.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who shoot the plane.

With the spirit of Juche idea, Kim Il Sung (Supreme leader of North Korea) can shoot planes with handgun easily. There is a selection from North Korea textbook:)

> General Kim Il Sung left the cave and saw several of the bombers from US imperialists bombarding the base continuously. The heroic People's Army soldiers kept shooting the American aircrafts but useless.
>
> Frowning angrily , the General saw an American aircraft tried to bomb again, he raised his handgun and aimed at the enemy aircraft. When the enemy is aligned the people army again and came down, the General shot. Shortly, a mass of huge fireball erupted in the sky with falling wreckage. The remaining US pilots were scared and escaped. Soldiers cheered toward the General Kim Il Sung:
>
> Long live the Great Leader Kim Il Sung!
>
> Long live the Great General Kim Il Sung!

But for other people, it seems impossible. Major damage of shooting comes from explosive within warhead. In WWII, most of the fighters installed 20mm machine gun or even larger, however, there is many case which the heavily shooted fighters have successfully landed on runways and aircraft carriers. Handgun even cannot kill a man for some times, how can it shot down a plane by most people?

Comment: Good example to put into perspective, thanks.

Comment: can even imagine that working, sorta. If you get lucky when shooting at a B-29 carrying a load of incendiary bombs (which are very thin walled containers filled with white phosphorous in those days) you may well set off a chain reaction resulting in said fireball. Unlikely to do with a pistol at the range they'd be, but turn a high power scoped rifle into a pistol for artistic license...

Comment: Omg someone trusts that is true

Answer (score 2):

Small arms fire absolutely can take down aircraft: http://www.lonesentry.com/articles/defga/ (WW2)

> In one instance in Africa, an eye-witness reported the destruction of three Italian planes in 5 minutes by small-arms fire. In another case, the Germans claim to have brought down a Soviet plane with an automatic pistol.

[United States Army Air Defense Artillery School "Small Arms Defense"](https://fas.org/man/eprint/sad.pdf) describes tactical doctrine: saturate the region in front of the plane aircraft with lead and hope that enough hits are made to critically damage it.

Comment: Your first example is from WWII, not exactly comparable to modern commercial airliners.

Comment: Small arms in this context means assault rifles and light machine guns and backpacks full of ammunition. Quite a bit bigger than what normal people call a “handgun”.

Answer (score 1):

This when I got to give “the lawyers answer“ to:  Well, it depends...

It depends on the kind of gun that you use, where are you hit the airplane, and how much energy the bullet has at impact.

My basic answer would be that it’s very unlikely you could do this.

Some basics: handguns are notoriously inaccurate and under powered -  some firearms instructors go so far as to say the only purpose for a handgun is the fight your way back to a long gun.  The main purpose for such a firearm is as a compact means of self protection at close ranges and they were never intended for anti material use.  A typical handgun in the hands of an average shooter has an effective range of about 50-100 yards and packs about 300-700 Ft-Lbf of muzzle energy with poor ballistics (~1000 FPS, depending on model).  Larger handguns do pack a bit more energy (~1400 FPS and ~1500 Ft-lbf at the muzzle) but the application still remains the same.  This rules out the use of a gun against an airplane for anything but at point-blank range i.e. a guy hanging out at the fenceline of an airport taking a potshot at a 737 waiting to take off probably is either not going to hit it at all or with such poor accuracy that it can’t hit a vital system which could disable the airplane. Given the low muzzle energy of handguns, it’s unlikely that the round could penetrate critical components such as either the engines or the APU and disable them.   There is a chance though that’s such a round could penetrate the cabin of an aircraft and injure or kill a passenger.

As to whether a person could shoot an airplane flying overhead with a handgun, my response is no.  Airplanes are notoriously difficult to hit with firearms in flight and dedicated anti-aircraft systems will either utilize radar guided automatic weapons of a much more powerful round than a handgun uses, or large quantities of ballistic artillery shells fitted with proximity fuses and blast/fragmentation warheads to saturate an area where the aircraft is.   A single person with a handgun has virtually no chance of hitting an airplane like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the bullet is able to damage a tire, such that chunks of the tire fly off, those chunks could cause even more damage than just the bullet alone.  That was enough to bring down a Concorde (Flight 4590).

Comment: A handgun is very unlikely to shred an aircraft tyre, some may not even be able to cause a puncture. Even then, the Air France Concorde wasn't brought down directly by the damage but by a chain of unlikely events: the fuel leak was ignited by the afterburners (which most airliners don't have). The fire cause an engine alarm, and the (still functioning) engine was shut down, and the (overloaded) plane was unable to maintain flying speed on three engines. (Source: Aircrew Interview video)

Answer (score 0):

If the round from the handgun penetrated the partially-filled fuel tank of the aircraft, the ullage area would likely have a fuel vapour and air mixture and be prone to explosion leading to the separation of part of the wing from the aircraft. Large numbers of combat losses are attributed to this phenomenon before the introduction of either mechanical or chemical methods of preventing this fuel-air mixture from accumulating in the tanks of combat aircraft [even as recently as the mid 2000s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Royal_Air_Force_Hercules_shootdown).  Since this adds weight and potentially reduces available fuel capacity I don't believe this is included in civilian airliners.

So the answer to your question is yes.  If the aircraft were on short finals or just departing then your handgun round could possibly take down an airliner.

Answer (score -4):

If it pokes a hole, the pressure in the cabin will be lost (which involve possible injury to the ear drums or death of the people inside, as at cruise altitude there is not enough oxygen in the air for the human body, which is why it is pressurized inside and maintained at near sea level pressure).

The aircraft can be damaged to the point of losing a structural panel, but not necessarily crashing. Unless the pilot falls unconscious due to the lack of oxygen. (Oxygen mask only have about 15 minute of oxygen by the way).

If the bullet hits an engine, or poke the wing (i.e. fuel tank), then there is high risk of explosion, with dramatic consequences.

Comment: you are near ground already, no depressurization will happen.

also, explosions happen in films, hardly in real life.

Comment: Even if you are at altitude and suffer depressurization, 15 minutes is plenty enough to get down to a reasonably safe altitude even from jetliner cruise height. Even a [*normal landing descent* is on the order of 2000-2500 feet per minute](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8295/753) and that gets you from jetliner cruising altitude (30,000 feet) to ground level well within those 15 minutes. Also, even assuming the bullet penetrates the plane (see other answers), a handgun would punch a relatively tiny hole; it's not like that is going to cause instantaneous decompression.

Comment: It probably wouldn't cause significant decompression at all. The hole would be so small that you could just stick one of the in-flight magazines or something up against it and stop the leak completely (and this is assuming the plane is pressurized, which it probably wouldn't be.) Even if the plane were pressurized and no one bothered to plug the hole, the hole would be so small than the outflow would most likely be less than is already happening intentionally through the aircraft's outflow valve. And explosion will absolutely not happen. Jet fuel isn't explosive at normal pressure/temperature.

Comment: The cabin outflow valve would close a little in response to the cabin altitude change and they probably not find the hole for quite some time.  A few flights at least.