# Plane suddenly descending nose down, was it normal?

Tags: airbus-a320

I was on flight FR8710 Vie-SUF on 2023 May 1st, and the descent was quite abrupt, at least according to my standards (and to the other passengers' ones). I fly pretty often and this was the first time I experienced something like this; the flight was overall smooth until the plane suddenly "dropped" nose down for more or less 5 minutes. I can't remember if this was anticipated by a "prepare for landing" or similar announcement; usually I feel the smooth transition when the engine power is reduced, this time it was like a sudden unwanted uncomfortable undesired change in speed and tilt.
I felt really uncomfortable, and many around me confirmed they had similar feeling. It looked like the flight attendants had to suddenly rush operations and they did not look calm either. Now, SUF is not a really busy airport, the weather conditions looked fine, and no one was really expecting that.
Is there a way to understand what happened or if anything was just normal? Is there a way to understand if anything was filed regarding a procedure different than usual? I am no aviation expert (really far to be one actually) and I would really appreciate if anyone could give a hint here. From flightradar24 I can see the difference between a "normal" altitude drop and the one experienced in this flight.
I have checked previous similar questions on the StackExchange and learnt from the answers but they did not satisfy all my curiosity about the conditions I experienced on this flight, I hope you can help.

Edit: if I read the graph correctly (and we assume the data is accurate), between 6h24'33'' and 6h28'08'' there's a change in altitude from 33150 ft to 15800 ft, meaning ~4842 ft/min?!?

Thank you[image]

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8289/what-is-the-normal-descent-rate-for-airliners

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this but I cannot still understand what justified a descent of ~4842 ft/min

Comment: The flight was running late. Maybe they just wanted to get there faster?